# Python, save a matplotlib figure with output file name and output directory in a variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, argv

In my script, I want to take image name as an argument (argv) and do some image processing then save it an output directory with a filename like inputFileName_output.

```
# saving figure
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "./Output_Images_test"
outputfile = file.split(".")[0] + "__output.txt"
plt.savefig("%s/%s", dpi=300) %UPLOAD_FOLDER %outputfile
```

Comment: What are the errors and outputfile name?

Comment: It says no such file/directory exists. ``` fp = builtins.open(filename, "w+b")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '%s/%s.png' ```

Comment: I solved it using os.path.join and passed it to savefig. I was looking for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone runs into the same problem as me, here's what I did to solve it.
I joined the upload folder and outputfile using os.path.join.

```
# saving figure

outputfile_name = file.split(".")[0] + "__output.png"
output_image_path = os.path.join(UPLOAD_FOLDER, outputfile_name)
plt.savefig(output_image_path, dpi=300)
```